# Developer work in progress branches using SVN

Tags: svn

We just migrated to SVN at work, I pushed for Mercurial but that was rejected on the grounds that no one else working here had heard of it.

My current task requires me to hack to living crap out of a bespoke C++ build system in order to get it to play nicely with the new source control system. This will require massive change to the codebase.

The workflow I'm struggling to achieve is this:

- Branch trunk to some private area.
- Hack, including major structural tree changes
- Hack
- Hack
- Merge final result back into trunk.

A nice to have would be being able to periodically update my working branch from trunk, but for this project that it isn't a necessity since I'm the only guy working on this code.

Here are the problems I see with achieving this workflow.

Our SVN repository is structured like this:

```
SVN
    \_ Project1
        \_ trunk
        \_ branches
        \_ tags
        \_ shelves
            \_ dev1
            \_ dev2
    \_ Project2
    . . .
    \_ Project3
    . . .
```

Projects 2 and 3 have the same directory structure as Project 1. We created the shelves directory in the hope that developers would be able to branch and commit to assist development in the same way that they could using Git or Mercurial. Unfortunately I see no way that this can work using SVN. The problem is that once stuff is commited to SVN there is no way for other users to ignore it. So if I create 2 or 3 work in progress branches under Project1->shelves->Dev1 then the next time anyone else updates either Project 1 or their working copy of the entire repository it takes bloody ages as they have to wait for every new branch to be downloaded. Each new branch takes about 5 minutes to update, so with half a dozen developers creating 1 or more new work in progress branches each day it's completely unworkable.

If each developer could locally configure SVN to ignore the other devs private work in progress branch directories that would be perfect, but there appears to be no way to do this at all.

My other avenue of research was to consider using Mercurial or Git to checkout directly from SVN (Mercurial using hgsubversion and Git using git-svn). Both of these approaches have complexities arising from merging development branches back into the branch that needs to be commited to SVN but despite that complexity that approach held some promise. Until that is I did some testing and discovered that neither hgsubversion nor git-svn took any notice whatsoever of SVN file externals and I also came across some documentation that suggested that file renames/moves in Git would not be commited properly in SVN, i.e. the file history would be lost, which is not acceptable.

So right now what I'm looking at is this.

- Checking out my source using SVN.
- Copying the source to a new directory.
- hg init the new directory to give me a Mercurial working directory that I can hack.
- When I'm finished use KDiff3 to compare my final Mercurial working copy to the original SVN source.
- Use SVN move/rename/delete to manually fixup structural changes.
- Copy Mercurial working copy over SVN source and commit back to SVN.

There must be a better way. Please somebody help me find it!!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you wouldn't check out the whole repository like that - you'd only checkout the branch that you are working on (and use svn switch to move between branches)

Comment: Yah, you never check out the whole repo with SVN.  If that is what people you work with are doing, you need to get them to stop.